# Trying to call the JavaScript function from Java Source code

Tags: java, javascript, cordova

I am developing an Android App to read the barcode by using the Zxing Barcode reader Plugin.

In the plugin there is an object named window.plugins.barcodeScanner with which we encode/decode the barcode.

I don't wanna use HTML to invoke things instead want the below Javascript function to be called from Java [on click of the image- the below function would be invoked].

```
function scanCode(){
    window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function(result){
            alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text 
              + ". Format: " + result.format
              + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
        }, 
        function(error){
            alert("Scan failed: " + error);
        }
    );
}
```

Kindly let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: There are libraries for running JavaScript in Java.  Rhino comes to mind.  However, I doubt you will ever get the `windows.` stuff working, as there is no `window` in scope, since that comes from the browser.  Your other option might be to use a Java browser widget somehow, so that IT is loading the page on the app's behalf.

Comment: Is your app a phonegap application or you are trying to use the plugin alone within a strictly native app?

Comment: @UnchartedSpace : This is strictly a Native app and using the plugin alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- You've already setup the LibararyProject from https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/tree/master/src/android.
- Your Activity is not extending CordovaActivity but is extending Activity.
- Your main goal is really just to use the scanner. You were just trying to find an easy/quick way to do so and thought the PG plugin may do the trick.

All you have to do is pull out the scan and onActivityResult methods and some of the helper strings from https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/blob/master/src/android/com/phonegap/plugins/barcodescanner/BarcodeScanner.java and put them in your activity. You'll need to replace the references to cordova with your own activity.

End result may look something like this:

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0x0ba7c0de;
private static final String SCAN_INTENT = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";

public void scan() {
    Intent intentScan = new Intent(SCAN_INTENT);
    intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    this.startActivityForResult(intentScan, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String barcode = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            //Do whatever you need with the barcode here
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // handle a canceled scan
        } else {
            // throw an error or something
        }
    }
}
```

If that works for you, then you don't even need cordova as a dependancy.

Comment: Yes. It helps and this is what I expected. Thx alot!! Very Grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke Javascript code from native side on Android using the sendJavascript function defined in [CordovaWebView](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git;a=blob_plain;f=framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java;hb=HEAD).

In your case you would do something like this. Considering that the you want to call the following function:

`function scanSuccessCallback(result) {
  //do something
}`

on the native side in your plugin:

`this.webView.sendJavascript("scanSuccessCallback('the result');");`